# Issue with loading xml in C# containing google kml

Tags: c#, xml, kml

I am trying to access the second  element in this xml (google kml type) of file and the issue I am having is I get returned null values for my code unless I remove out the `<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">` and the related close from the source file. Here is the code I'm using. (mind you this works if I remove the specified line so what I'm looking for is a clean way to process this file without editing the supplied source file.)

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("2014_q2.xml");
        XmlNodeList xnlNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/kml/Document/Folder");
```

var Node2Use = xnlNodes.Item(1);

here is the top of the source file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
 <Document>
  <open>1</open>
  <Folder>
   <name>Pts_2014_q3_point Drawing</name>
   <Placemark>
    <description>HOLTSVILLE</description>
    <name>00501</name>
    <Style>
     <IconStyle>
      <color>ffc0c0c0</color>
```

I have a break on the `var Node2Use = xnlNodes.Item(1);` line so I can see the contents and thats where I see that I have a zero value where I should have 2 for Folder (like mentioned I get the 2 when I remove out that kml tagged line.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the namespace. Something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("2014_q2.xml");

XNamespace ns = "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0";

XmlNodeList xnlNodes = doc.SelectNodes(ns + "/kml/Document/Folder");
```

Comment: I am trying to work that snippet in but the errors I am encountering with it arent working I changed it slightly:
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
           doc.Load("2014_q2.xml");
//            XmlNode FolderListNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Folder");


            var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("somename", "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0");
            var xnlNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//somename:/Document/Folder");
var Node2Use = xnlNodes.Item(1);